# FCM notification click event not getting triggered

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications to my Angular PWA app using FCM notification.

PFB the firebase-messaging-sw.js script that I am using

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
    const app = firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCPDma5gSKIroVpVNs3qMjOHyc-LS0NYV8",
        authDomain: "notification-2-fd7b0.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "notification-2-fd7b0",
        storageBucket: "notification-2-fd7b0.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "754626352472",
        appId: "1:754626352472:web:7244f969b1de31a74cc12d",
        measurementId: "G-QB0K3YEKFX"
    });
    
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    // Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
    // messages.
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    })
```

When the fcm notifications are clicked "notificationclick" event is not getting triggered in my Angular PWA application.